# How do I code for gestures in a SKScene in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am in the process of learning to develop iOS apps in Swift and I am currently tasked with coding for different swipe gestures.  I looked up a few things in the documentation, and finally wrote this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let down = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 20, duration: 1)

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "logo")
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    func swipedDown(gesture:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        sprite.run(down)
    }

    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("swipedDown:")))
    swipeDown.direction = .down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}

}
```

Upon swiping down in the resulting app, however, I receive an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.  I've tried a few different things to fix it, but nothing is working.

I am using Xcode 8 GM with Swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your code to the following to make it work with Swift 3.

```
let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipedDown(_:)))
swipeDown.direction = .down
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

func swipedDown(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
     print("Swiped down")
}
```